# Do subtraction between columns of a data.frame

Tags: r

The database below presents the ranking of three methods, which I called `M1`, `M2` and `M3`. Therefore, I would like to make a new dataset with the difference between the ranks of two methods. In this case, the following relation would be, M1 and M2, M1 and M3, M2 and M3. Therefore, the dataset will have three columns (n, M1-M2, M1-M3 and M2-M3).

```
result<-structure(list(n = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 
28, 29), M1 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L), M2 = c(1, 29, 28, 27, 26, 25, 
24, 23, 22, 21, 20, 15, 12, 19, 18, 17, 16, 14, 13, 11, 10, 9, 
8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2), M3 = c(1L, 29L, 28L, 27L, 25L, 26L, 24L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 15L, 12L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 16L, 13L, 14L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 4L, 2L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-29L))
  
    > result
    n M1 M2 M3
1   1  1  1  1
2   2 29 29 29
3   3 28 28 28
4   4 27 27 27
5   5 25 26 25
6   6 26 25 26
7   7 24 24 24
8   8 20 23 20
9   9 21 22 21
10 10 22 21 22
11 11 23 20 23
12 12 15 15 15
13 13 12 12 12
14 14 17 19 17
15 15 18 18 18
16 16 19 17 19
17 17 16 16 16
18 18 13 14 13
19 19 14 13 14
20 20  5 11  5
21 21  6 10  6
22 22  7  9  7
23 23  8  8  8
24 24  9  7  9
25 25 10  6 10
26 26 11  5 11
27 27  4  4  4
28 28  2  3  2
29 29  3  2  3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `tidyverse` solution you can use `mutate()` from the `dplyr` package to create new columns in your data.frame:

```r
library(dplyr)

newDF <- result %>% 
  mutate(D1 = M1-M2, D2 = M1-M3, D3 = M2 - M3)
```

**Output:**

```
    n M1 M2 M3 D1 D2 D3
1   1  1  1  1  0  0  0
2   2 29 29 29  0  0  0
3   3 28 28 28  0  0  0
4   4 27 27 27  0  0  0
5   5 25 26 25 -1  0  1
6   6 26 25 26  1  0 -1
7   7 24 24 24  0  0  0
8   8 20 23 20 -3  0  3
9   9 21 22 21 -1  0  1
10 10 22 21 22  1  0 -1
11 11 23 20 23  3  0 -3
12 12 15 15 15  0  0  0
13 13 12 12 12  0  0  0
14 14 17 19 17 -2  0  2
15 15 18 18 18  0  0  0
16 16 19 17 19  2  0 -2
17 17 16 16 16  0  0  0
18 18 13 14 13 -1  0  1
19 19 14 13 14  1  0 -1
20 20  5 11  5 -6  0  6
21 21  6 10  6 -4  0  4
22 22  7  9  7 -2  0  2
23 23  8  8  8  0  0  0
24 24  9  7  9  2  0 -2
25 25 10  6 10  4  0 -4
26 26 11  5 11  6  0 -6
27 27  4  4  4  0  0  0
28 28  2  3  2 -1  0  1
29 29  3  2  3  1  0 -1
```

Comment: Thanks for reply! Please, more one question if you can reply: if I want to sum all the numbers in column D1, sum all the numbers in column D2 and sum all the values ​​in column D3, you know?

Comment: You can sum any variable (i.e. column) of a data frame with the built-in `sum()` function. You need to pass it the name of the data frame and the name of the variable separated by a dollar sign: `sum(newDF$D1)` returns `0`. To quickly add a totals row to your data frame use the `janitor` package: `newDF %>% adorn_totals("row")`.

Answer (score 3):

We can try

```
cbind(
  result,
  `colnames<-`(
    combn(result[-1], 2, function(v) v[[1]] - v[[2]]),
    combn(names(result)[-1], 2, function(v) paste0(v, collapse = "-"))
  )
)
```

which gives

```
    n M1 M2 M3 M1-M2 M1-M3 M2-M3
1   1  1  1  1     0     0     0
2   2 29 29 29     0     0     0
3   3 28 28 28     0     0     0
4   4 27 27 27     0     0     0
5   5 25 26 25    -1     0     1
6   6 26 25 26     1     0    -1
7   7 24 24 24     0     0     0
8   8 20 23 20    -3     0     3
9   9 21 22 21    -1     0     1
10 10 22 21 22     1     0    -1
11 11 23 20 23     3     0    -3
12 12 15 15 15     0     0     0
13 13 12 12 12     0     0     0
14 14 17 19 17    -2     0     2
15 15 18 18 18     0     0     0
16 16 19 17 19     2     0    -2
17 17 16 16 16     0     0     0
18 18 13 14 13    -1     0     1
19 19 14 13 14     1     0    -1
20 20  5 11  5    -6     0     6
21 21  6 10  6    -4     0     4
22 22  7  9  7    -2     0     2
23 23  8  8  8     0     0     0
24 24  9  7  9     2     0    -2
25 25 10  6 10     4     0    -4
26 26 11  5 11     6     0    -6
27 27  4  4  4     0     0     0
28 28  2  3  2    -1     0     1
29 29  3  2  3     1     0    -1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result = cbind(n=result$n,(result[,c(2:4)] - result[,c(3,4,2)])[,c(1,3,2)])
names(result)=c("n", "M1-M2", "M1-M3", "M2-M3")
```

Output:

```
    n M1-M2 M1-M3 M2-M3
1   1     0     0     0
2   2     0     0     0
3   3     0     0     0
4   4     0     0     0
5   5    -1     0     1
6   6     1     0    -1
7   7     0     0     0
8   8    -3     0     3
9   9    -1     0     1
10 10     1     0    -1
11 11     3     0    -3
12 12     0     0     0
13 13     0     0     0
14 14    -2     0     2
15 15     0     0     0
16 16     2     0    -2
17 17     0     0     0
18 18    -1     0     1
19 19     1     0    -1
20 20    -6     0     6
21 21    -4     0     4
22 22    -2     0     2
23 23     0     0     0
24 24     2     0    -2
25 25     4     0    -4
26 26     6     0    -6
27 27     0     0     0
28 28    -1     0     1
29 29     1     0    -1
```

Answer (score -1):

Its a dataframe so you should be able to do something like

`result$M1_M2 <- result$M1 - result$M2`

or something similar